# Products to Sums and Sums to Products Identitites

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having trouble proving the below statement using the product to sums and sums to product identities in trigonometry:

We were told to use the the result
$$\sin A\sin B = \frac12 \left(\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)\;\right)$$
to prove that
$$\sin x + \sin 3x + \sin 5x + \cdots + \sin(2n-1)x = \frac{\sin^2 nx}{\sin x}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\sin x \ne 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sin((2i - 1)x) & =
\frac{\sin x}{\sin x}\sum_{i=1}^n \sin((2i - 1)x) \\
& = \frac 1{\sin x}\sum_{i=1}^n \sin((2i - 1)x) \sin x.
\end{align*}
Now use the given formula for each summand on the right-hand side:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sin((2i - 1)x)
& = \frac 1{\sin x}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 12(\cos(2(i - 1)x) - \cos(2ix)).
\end{align*}
The sum on the right-hand side is telescoping, so
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sin((2i - 1)x) & =
\frac 1{\sin x}\left(\frac{1 - \cos(2nx)}2\right) \\
& = \frac{\sin^2(nx)}{\sin x}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you! I just have two more questions; how do we know that the sum on the right hand side is telescoping? And where is the 1-cos(2nx) coming from?

Comment: Whenever you have a sum of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n (a_{i-1} - a_i)$, you can rearrange it as $$\left(a_0 + \sum_{i=2}^n a_{i-1}\right) - \left(a_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i\right).$$ Reindex the first summation to $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i$, and you can see that the two summations cancel, leaving you with $a_0 - a_n$. In this particular problem, $a_i = \cos(2ix)$, so you are left with $a_0 - a_n = \cos(0) - \cos(2nx)$.